# How to add styles to dynamically created component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set styles to dynamically created components.

I want to do something like this, because what i want can't be done with s/css styles (class or id).

```
<div [style.height]="myVar">
```

The components that i'm creating are:

```
let widgetResourceGroupFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ResourceGroupComponent);

for (let group of this.groups) {
  let widgetResourceGroupReference = this.content.createComponent(widgetResourceGroupFactory);  

  widgetResourceGroupReference.instance['group'] = group;
  widgetResourceGroupReference.instance['slug'] = group.slug;

  this.renderer.listen(widgetResourceGroupReference.location.nativeElement, 'click', () => {
    this.loadCategories(group);
  });
}
```

I want to set a custom style to `widgetResourceGroupReference`, but what i was trying didn't work, that was a sort of `instance['style.height']`.

Thanks u very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i solved it with renderer:

```
this.renderer.setElementStyle(widgetResourceGroupReference.location.nativeElement, 'width', this.upperLeftWidth);
```